# Create Conda environment on top of existing installation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment, miniconda

I have installed miniconda3 on a system using the bash installation script, then performed a `conda install` of some packages into this installation.

This installation is available to other users in a read-only fashion. They can source a setup script that adds the conda installation to their `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `PATH`, and `PYTHONPATH`.

I would like the user to be able to add their own custom modules on top of this environment.

Ideally the user would run some form of `conda create` environment that results in the user being able to install packages in their local environment, but takes the previously installed packages from my area.

Is there a good way to do this?

The important point for this is that my conda installation has some architecture specific libraries which are needed to get proper performance on the computer system we have. If a user does a standard `conda create ...` everything is installed from scratch and the user does not get the proper libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to clone the base Conda environment. You just need to use the `--clone` argument with the create command. See the link to documentation below:

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#cloning-an-environment

Comment: Great thanks. That is exactly what I needed and I can pass the PATH to the installation to the `--clone` argument.

Comment: This process yields a warning when applied to the `base` environment: (anaconda 5.2) `The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment... `.

Comment: the path is broken

Answer (score 0):

This method really saved me a lot. You can export an existing environment and create a new one based on all of the installed packages in the existing one:

```
$ conda env export > FILE_NAME.yml
```

and then you can bring this file to another machine or simply do the creation on your current machine:

```
$ conda env create -f FILE_NAME.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

`conda create` (or conda env create), will overwrite and reset the environment directory. You should rather activate the existing environment, and install additional packages:

```
# Create Conda environment, only if it does not already exists
$ [[ $(conda env list | grep my_env) ]] || conda create -y -n my_env

$ source activate my_env

(my_env)$ conda install -y --update-deps new_package

(my_env)$ conda list
# previous packages + new_package
```